# Angular 2 REST request HTTP status code 401 changes to 0

Tags: rest, angular, cors

I'm developing an Angular2 application.  It seems when my access-token expires the 401 HTTP Status code gets changed to a value of 0 in the Response object.  I'm receiving 401 Unauthorized yet the ERROR Response object has a status of 0.  This is preventing me from trapping a 401 error and attempting to refresh the token.  What's causing the 401 HTTP status code to be changed into HTTP status code of 0?

Here's screenshot from Firefox's console:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> 
{
    //console.log('GET REQUEST...', url);

    return super.get(url, options)
        .catch((err: Response): any =>
        {
            console.log('************* ERROR Response', err);

            if (err.status === 400 || err.status === 422)
            {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
            //NOT AUTHENTICATED
            else if (err.status === 401)
            {                   
                this.authConfig.DeleteToken();
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }               
            else
            {
                // this.errorService.notifyError(err);
                // return Observable.empty();
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        })
        // .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500))
        // .timeout(2000, new Error('delay exceeded'))
        .finally(() =>
        {
            //console.log('After the request...');
        });
}
```

This code resides in a custom http service that extends Angular2's HTTP so I can intercept errors in a single location.

In Google Chrome, I get this error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudcms.com/repositories/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/branches/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/nodesXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://screwtopmedia.local.solutiaconsulting.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

This is confusing because I am including 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in request.

Here's a picture of results received in Google Chrome:

[image]

I've tried accessing 'WWW-Authenticate' Response Header as a means to trap for 401.  However, the following code returns a NULL:

```
err.headers.get("WWW-Authenticate")
```

It's puzzling that I'm getting a CORS issue because I'm not getting any CORS errors when a valid access token is provided.

How do I trap for 401 HTTP status code?  Why is 401 HTTP status code being changed to 0?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If cloudcms.com do to not set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in 401 response, then nothing much you can do. You properly have to open support ticket with them to confirm if that is normal behavior.

javascript in browsers(FF, Chrome & Safari) I tested won't receive any info if CORS error occur, other than status 0. Angular2 has no control of it.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I mean in the case server dont send corrects code, but on the chrome console you see 401, but angular keeps giving 0 like status ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work for Cloud CMS. I can confirm that we properly set CORS headers on API calls. However, for 401 responses the headers are not getting set properly. This has been resolved and the fix will be available on the public API at the end of this week.

BTW if you use our javascript driver https://github.com/gitana/gitana-javascript-driver instead of writing to the API directly then the re-auth flow is handled automatically and you do not need to trap 401 errors at all.

Answer (score 25):

The issue is related to **CORS requests**, see [**this github issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3336)

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

means that `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` is required in the response headers.

Angular is not getting any status codes, that's why it gives you a `0` which is caused by browser not allowing the `xml parser` to parse the `response` due to invalid `headers`.

You need to append correct **CORS headers** to your `error response` as well as `success`.

Comment: so, the response from the 3rd party source needs 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in headers too?  I've added it with my request.

Comment: This status code is still weird to be honest, why would Google say it's a CORS request problem and not Firefox ?

Comment: it's not firefox because i get the same issue in Google Chrome

Comment: @TomSchreck exactly

Answer (score 8):

If cloudcms.com do to not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in 401 response, then nothing much you can do. You properly have to open support ticket with them to confirm if that is normal behavior.

javascript in browsers(FF, Chrome & Safari) I tested won't receive any info if CORS error occur, other than status 0. Angular2 has no control of it.

---

I created a simple test and get the same result as yours:

```
geturl() {
    console.log('geturl() clicked');
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ 'headers': headers });
    this.http.get(this.url)
        .catch((error): any => {
            console.log('************* ERROR Response', error);
            let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Web Server error';
            return Observable.throw(error);
        })
        .subscribe(
        (i: Response) => { console.log(i); },
        (e: any) => { console.log(e); }
        );
}
```

After much googling, I found the following(https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3336):

> lucassp commented on Aug 19, 2013
>
> I found the issue for a while now but I forgot post here a reply. EVERY response, even Error 500, must have the CORS headers attached. If the server doesn't attach the CORS headers to the Error 500 response then the XHR Object won't parse it, thus the XHR Object won't have any response body, status, or any other response data inside.

Result from Firefox network monitor seems supporting the above reason.

Javascript request will receive empty response.
[image: javascript request]

Plain url request(copy&paste the link in the address bar) will get response body
[image: Plain url request]

Javascript use XHRHttpRequest for http communication.

When a XHR reply arrive, the browser will process the header, that's why you will see those 401 network messages. However, if the XHR reply is from a different host then the javascript AND the response header contain no CORS header(eg `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`), the browser will not pass any info back to the XHR layer. As a result, the reply body will be completely empty with no status(0).

I tested with FF 48.0.1, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 and Safari 9.1.2, and they all have the same behavior.

Use browser network monitor to check response header for those `401 Unauthorized` entries, it is very likely that there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and causing the issue you are facing. This can be a bug or by design on the service provider side.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response only http header. For more information of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this item:

What happens in my case was that:

- I was requesting REST from different domain
- The resource returned 401, but there was no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" set in the error response.
- Chrome (or your browser) received 401 and showed in network tab (See below count : 401), but never passed to Angular

[image]

- since there was no CORS allowed (missing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header) - Chrome could not pass this response into Angular. This way I could see 401 in the Chrome but not in Angular.
- Solution was simple (extends on TimothyBrake's answer) - to add the missing header into the error response. In Spring boot I put: `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` and I was sorted out.

> ```
> @Component
> public class JwtUnauthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint
>   implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
>   @Override
>   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
>           AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
>
>       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
>       response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
>               "You would need to provide the Jwt Token to Access This resource");
>   }
> }
> ```

PS: Make sure the bean is provided into HttpSecurity config in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Refer to: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication if in doubt.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute), if the status attribute is set to 0, it means that:

- The state is UNSENT or OPENED.

or

- The error flag is set.

I think that this isn't an `Angular2` issue, it seems like your request has a problem.

Comment: interesting.  How do you fix this?

Comment: the request is getting sent to REST URL because I'm getting a 401 status code.  I can see 401 Unauthorized in the results.  But when I get to the provided response, the status code is 0.  So, an UNSENT state doesn't seem correct.

Comment: In my case - Angular never gets this request - it is blocked by the browser because of missing CORS attributes returned with error.

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba yes you're right, as I m thinking the same so how we fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was due to the server not sending the correct response (even though the console log stated a 401 the Angular error had status 0). My server was Tomcat with Java application using Spring MVC and Spring Security.

It is now working using folowing setup:

SecurityConfig.java

```
...
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
....
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    // allow CORS option calls
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();
 ...
```

SomeAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component
public class SomeAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpStatus responseStatus = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
    response.sendError(responseStatus.value(), responseStatus.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/errors/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/errors/unauthorised</location>
</error-page>
```

Controller to handle the /errors/... previously defined

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/errors")
public class SecurityExceptionController {

    @RequestMapping("forbidden")
    public void resourceNotFound() throws Exception {
        // Intentionally empty
    }

    @RequestMapping("unauthorised")
    public void unAuthorised() throws Exception {
        // Intentionally empty
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response.  The service I'm consuming is a 3rd party service.  So, I do not have control over/access to their server.  Any idea why I can see 401 status code in console, yet the error object in Angular has status code of 0?  This speaks to the issue being Angular and not the server.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a 3rd party http protocol monitor (like CharlesProxy) rather than Chrome dev tools to confirm which headers are actually being sent to the API service and if it is returning a 401.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I'm using Postman as well and can see 401 Unauthorized status returned from the 3rd party API calls when submitting an expired token.  So, I do not believe the issue is with the 3rd party service.  It seems the error response object's error status is getting changed from 401 to 0 somewhere in the internals of Angular2.