# Why I am not able to handle 401 error

Tags: angular

[image]

I am trying to handle 401 error in my application but the error response is giving me this

[image]

my code snippet

```js
// service

  postPickupData(form: any) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
    const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    this.token = userInfo.token;
    console.log(this.token);
    const headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    });
  // headers.append("auth-token", this.token);
  // headers.append("user-id", userInfo.uidx);
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(form);
    this.loggedIn = true;
    return (
      this.http
        .post(this.API, form, options)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  
  
  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.log(error);
if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
return Observable.throw("Unauthorised");
}

  }
```

I have a post request and an handleError method which should throw unauthorised. I am also importing throw from observable and map and catch from rxjs

Comment: Your console.log status states that it's `0` instead of `401`, therefore it doesn't hit the `if` statement, and doesn't return anything, thus the current error message. As why it returns `0`, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999235/angular2-rest-request-http-status-code-401-changes-to-0